# How to create a vector from a constant in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, tensor

How is it that you would create a tensorflow vector from a tensorflow constant/variable etc?
For example I have a constant `x` and I want to create a vector which is `[x]`.

I have tried the code below and it doesn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
x = tf.placeholder_with_default(1.0,[], name="x")
nextdd = tf.constant([x], shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Do you want `nextdd` be a const or a variable?

Comment: I guess it would be a variable based on the value of x. 
The fact that I used constant is wrong in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you description, it looks like you want to use [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims):

```
# 't' is a tensor of shape [2]
tf.shape(tf.expand_dims(t, 0))  # [1, 2]
tf.shape(tf.expand_dims(t, 1))  # [2, 1]
tf.shape(tf.expand_dims(t, -1))  # [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

First I'd like to define a tensor for you:

Tensors are n-dimensional matrices. A rank 0 tensor is a scalar, e.g. 42. a rank 1 tensor is a Vector, e.g. [1,2,3], a rank 2 tensor is a matrix, a rank 3 tensor might be an image of shape [640, 480, 3] (640x480 resolution, 3 color channels). a rank 4 tensor might be a batch of such images of shape [10, 640, 480, 3] (10 640x480 images), etc.

Second, you have basically 4 types of tensors in Tensorflow.

1) Placeholders - these are tensors that you pass into tensorflow when you call `sess.run`. For example: `sess.run([nextdd], {x:[1,2,3]})` creates a rank 1 tensor out of `x`.

2) Constants - these are fixed values as the name suggests. E.g. `tf.constant(42)` and should be specified at compile time, not runtime (eluding to your primary mistake here).

3) Computed tensors - `x = tf.add(a,b)` is a computed tensor, it's computed from a,b. Its value is not stored after the computation is finished.

4) Variables - These are mutable tensors that are kept around after the computation is complete. For example the weights of a neural network.

Now to address your question explicitly. `x` is already a tensor. If you were passing in a vector then it's a rank 1 tensor (aka a vector). You can use it just like you'd use a constant, computed tensor, or variable. They all work the same in operations. There is no reason for the nextdd line at all.

Now, `nextdd` fails becuase you tried to create a constant from a variable term, which isn't a defined operation. `tf.constant(42)` is well defined, that's what a constant is.

You could just use x directly, as in:

```
x = tf.placeholder_with_default(1.0,[], name="x")
y = tf.add(x, x)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
y.eval()
```

Result:

```
2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I actually prefer Maxim's. 
Its more direct.