# tensorflow 'ScatterNdUpdate' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to update a tensor using scatter_nd_update, my code is as follows:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
            self.W = tf.Variable(
                tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
                name="W")
            self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
            updates = tf.constant(0,shape=[embedding_size])
            for i in range(1,sequence_length - 2):
                indices = [None,i]
                tf.scatter_nd_update(self.embedded_chars,indices,updates)
            self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)
```

However, got the error saying:

TypeError: 'ScatterNdUpdate' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)

I know the reason is that self.embedded_chars as the parameter to scatter_nd_update is not mutable.

My question is how can I define the self.embedded_chars so it can be passed to scatter_nd_update function?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I found two other similar questions, one on Github(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2358), the other on Google Group(https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/c_9lY5Id0yc).  However, neither were resolved. It seems troublesome. Anybody has a idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just computing a value that you will use later then just use `tf.scatter_nd` there's no reason to apply an update. I suggest reading this post that talks about [the various types of tensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349702/how-to-create-a-vector-from-a-constant-in-tensorflow/49350002#49350002) in tensorflow, which I won't repeat here.

If you don't need to maintain this value from one call to `sess.run` to the next, then `tf.scatter_nd` is the correct solution. If you are trying to maintain the value from one call to `sess.run` to the next then you'll need to create a variable for this value first, then apply assing:

```
mutable_variable = tf.Variable(<initial-value>, name=<optional-name>)
with tf.control_dependencies(cost):
  tf.scatter_nd_update(mutable_variable, indices, updates)
```

If you follow this second approach then notice that I added `tf.control_dependencies` because the assign operation will not have any dependencies, this is a common problem for assign operations. If there is no dependency it will not be executed in the normal course of a `sess.run` call unless you explicitly ask it to be executed, adding a dependency (in this case on the cost function just as an example) manually adds a dependency so it will be executed any time `cost` is computed.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. As you see the self.embedded_chars is generated from embedding_lookup operation. and I need to set part of tensors inside it to zero, and also later with some add or subtraction operation on these tensors. So I think I need to use it. If I understand your answer correctly,  I should take the second approach you suggested. One more question, can I initialize a new variable from the exist one. e.g., can I write like following,  mutable_variable = tf.Variable(self.embedded_chars) ? Thank you.

Comment: I rewrite it as following:  self.embedded_chars = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64,sequence_length,embedding_size]))
            self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
            updates = tf.constant(0,shape=[embedding_size])
            for i in range(1,sequence_length - 2):
                indices = [0,i]
                tf.scatter_nd_update(self.embedded_chars,indices,updates)
However, still the same problem, TypeError: 'ScatterNdUpdate' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)

Comment: You have `self.embedded_chars = ...` in two statements, you're just overwriting it and making the first statement meaningless.

Comment: I write self.embedded_chars = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64,sequence_length,embedding_size]))  because I want to make self.embedded_chars be mutable. I really confused how to modify the content of the self.embedded_char. Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has answered in another related question, accessible via
[How to modify the return tensor from tf.nn.embedding_lookup()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259009/how-to-modify-the-return-tensor-from-tf-nn-embedding-lookup)