# How to modify the return tensor from tf.nn.embedding_lookup()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, embedding, tensor

I want to use `scatter_nd_update` to change the content of the tensor returned from `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`. However, the returned tensor is not mutable, and the `scatter_nd_update()` require an mutable tensor as input.
I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution, including using `gen_state_ops._temporary_variable` and using `tf.sparse_to_dense`, unfortunately all failed.

I wonder is there a beautiful solution toward it?

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
            self.W = tf.Variable(
                tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
                name="W")
            self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
            updates = tf.constant(0,shape=[embedding_size])
            for i in range(1,sequence_length - 2):
                indices = [None,i]
                tf.scatter_nd_update(self.embedded_chars,indices,updates)
            self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.nn.embedding_lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) simply returns the slice of the larger matrix, so the simplest solution is to update the value of *that* matrix itself, in your case it's `self.W`:

```
self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
```

Since it's a variable, it is compliant with [`tf.scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update). Note that you can't update just *any* tensor, only *variables*.

Another option is to create a new variable just for the selected slice, assign `self.embedded_chars` to it and perform an update afterwards.

---

Caveat: in both cases, you're blocking the gradients to train the embedding matrix, so double check that overwriting the learned value is really what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Could you say more about the caveat. I want to modify some tensors at the input layers, such as doing some add or subtraction.

Comment: It's ok to modify the raw input data (called pre-processing). What you describe in the question is overwritting the value in the middle of training. Or probably I don't understand your goal here.

Comment: I think I am doing pre-processing, because it's done before convolution happens. I want to concatenate each word embedding or make a subtraction to get the embedding offset, then feed to the convolution layer. So I think it won't ruin the training. Isn't it?

Comment: No and it's important. The embedding is *learnable* (unless it's pre-trained and fixed), so it's already part of the network. Pre-processing is done to the data *before* you feed it in, in this case character indices.

Comment: I use the pre-training word2vec embedding trained on Google corpus(GoogleNews-vectors-negative300). It is loaded in the self.W. Then by using embedding_lookup to get the vectors for each word in a sentence and as input. What I want to do is concatenate or subtract among these word vectors at the input layer, then feed to the convolution layer. I think only the weights matrix is learnable and the embeddings at the input layer are fixed. Am I right?

Comment: Could you please speak more detail about the second option you mentioned? I am not very clear of it. Thanks.

Comment: I follow the second option, but still get the same error saying 'ref' not mutable.         
tslice = tf.Variable(tf.fill([64,sequence_length,embedding_size],0)). 
tslice = tf.slice(self.embedded_chars,[64,0,0],[1,sequence_length,embedding_size]). 
  indices = [[0,i]]  
  update = tf.scatter_nd_update(tslice,indices,updates).         The error is: TypeError: 'ScatterNdUpdate' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)

Comment: Hi @Maxim, can you help to see the problem again? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @zenna, I see you encountered similar problem. Did you got your problem solved? If yes, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem rooted from not clearly understand the tensor and variable in the tensorflow context. Later with more knowledge of the tensor, the solution came to my mind is:

```
   with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        self.W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
            name="W")
        self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.input_x)
        for i in range(0,sequence_length - 1,2):
            self.tslice = tf.slice(self.embedded_chars,[0,i,0],[0,1,128])
            self.tslice2 = tf.slice(self.embedded_chars,[0,i+1,0],[0,1,128])
            self.tslice3 = tf.slice(self.embedded_chars,[0,i+2,0],[0,1,128])
            self.toffset1 = tf.subtract(self.tslice,self.tslice2)
            self.toffset2 = tf.subtract(self.tslice2,self.tslice3)
            self.tconcat = tf.concat([self.toffset1,self.toffset2],1)
        self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)
```

the function used, tf.slice, tf.subtract, tf.concat all accept tensor as input. Just avoid using function like tf.scatter_nd_update that require variable as input.